# While save out contents of a QGLWidget as an image, text in the widget are not saved

Tags: qt, opengl

In My QGLWidet, I draw some text using method renderText(). Then, I want to save the contents of the widget as an image. But, it turns out that text drawn by renderText() are not saved out.

```
void MyGLWidget::paintGL()
{
    qglClearColor(Qt::white);
    glViewport(0,0, width(), height());
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glColor3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2f(0,0);
    glVertex2f(width(), height());
    glEnd();

    renderText(50, 50,  "Hello");
    glColor3f(0.0,1.0,0.0);
    renderText(50, 150, "World");
}
```

Here is code to save image:

```
void MyGLWidget::saveImage()
{
    QGLPixelBuffer pbuffer(width(), height());
    pbuffer.makeCurrent();
    paintGL();
    QImage image = pbuffer.toImage();
    image.save("test_image.tif","tif");
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: did you try calling `glFlush();` at the end of `paintGL()`?

Comment: i have tried adding glFlush(), it still not work.

Comment: renderText is probably drawing using native functions rendered ontop of the openGL surface and so isn't seen by the pixel buffer

Answer (score 1):

After debugging into Qt 4.8.0's source code, I found a few reasons this will not work.

1. renderText uses GLWidget's width & height rather than the QGLPixelBuffer (not an issue for your case as your screenshot & widget are the same size)
2. It constructs a QPainter on the QGLWidget to render the text

Unfortunately, it looks like renderText is simply incompatible w/ QGLPixelBuffers